# How to create "*.rc" resource files with contents using Makefile?

Tags: makefile

I would like to know the command, to create *.rc file in a folder of having image files and also I want to write preprocessor statements in the *.rc files.

Please provide me some suggestion, how to achieve this using makefile.

I have tried the below command to create *.rc file,

```
%.rc: $(BITMAPS)
    $(file > $@.rc, $^)
```

Comment: I don't think you can get a .rc file from the makefile...

Comment: Quick googling does not unambiguously allow to identify the platform of your question.  Are you talking about Windows RC files?  What exactly would you like to produce the file from?  Just a bunch of BMP bitmaps?

Comment: What exactly do you expect the following code to do? `%.rc: $(BITMAPS) $(file > $@.rc, $^)`

Comment: http://rj-graffix.com/development/winrsrc.html looks vaguely helpful, but without the identifiers from your code to tell which symbol represents which bitmap file, it's impossible.  How would you specify this mapping?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `*.rc` file is plain text, you can use a scripting language to write it from some other sort of definition.  Here is a simple Perl script.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

print <<HERE;
#include <WINDOWS.h>
#include <UPPERCASE_MONSTROSITY.h>
HERE

for my $file (@ARGV) {
    my $basename = $file;
    $basename =~ s/\.BMP$//;
    print "$basename BITMAP DISCARDABLE \"$filename\"\n";
}
```

Assuming you saved this as `makerc`, you can run it from Make like

```
resources.rc: $(BITMAPS)  # assuming $(BITMAPS) is something like $(wildcard *.BMP)
    perl makerc $^ >$@
```